# document.getElementById on the canvas return null

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to javascript and I'm learning about it. While doing so I encountered this problem which I can't figure out and I'm here for your help.

This is the page that I was on, http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_empty

Now I when I run the following on the console(firebug) it returned null.

```
document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

Why I'm I not getting the expected result here?

Comment: That page uses an iframe to hold the sample document. Your console was looking in the main page.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I wouldn't have figured it out on my own.

Comment: Most devtools allow you to chose in which iframe you want to run code.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM has already been loaded when the draw-function is called, that is correct.

But the var canvas = document.getElementById('control');-line is evaluated before that, because it is not in the draw-function. It is executed immediately in the  of the document BEFORE the elements have been rendered.

I would suggest you change your init function to something like that

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```